# SDL2 SDL_CreateRenderer downgrades the OpenGL context, can it be prevented?

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-3, sdl-2

I am on Mac OS (10.9.3). I can create a window + context which is a 3.3 Context as requested. But once I create the renderer SDL tells me that the renderer is invalid. Apart from that I can use the renderer to draw and copy textures. But creating the renderer also seems to change the OpenGL context to a 2.1 profile :(

Is there a way to prevent that?

**[EDIT]**

SDL2 and glew are linked as a static library. glewExperimental is not set to GL_TRUE.

C++ source:

```
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 3);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_CORE);

SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_ACCELERATED_VISUAL, 1);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE, 24);


h_main_window = SDL_CreateWindow(
    title.c_str(), 
    SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 
    SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, 
    width, 
    height, 
    SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN
)

SDL_GL_CreateContext(h_main_window)
glewInit()

std::cout << "gl_renderer:" << glGetString(GL_RENDERER) << std::endl;
std::cout << "gl_context: " << glGetString(GL_VERSION) << std::endl;
std::cout << "gl_shading_lang_version: " << glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION) << std::endl;

SDL_CreateRenderer(
    h_main_window,
    -1,
    SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC | SDL_RENDERER_TARGETTEXTURE
)

std::cout << "gl_renderer:" << glGetString(GL_RENDERER) << std::endl;
std::cout << "gl_context: " << glGetString(GL_VERSION) << std::endl;
std::cout << "gl_shading_lang_version: " << glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION) << std::endl;

initShaders()
```

Output:

```
gl_renderer:Intel HD Graphics 3000 OpenGL Engine
gl_context: 3.3 INTEL-8.24.13
gl_shading_lang_version: 3.30

SDL Error: Invalid renderer

gl_renderer:Intel HD Graphics 3000 OpenGL Engine
gl_context: 2.1 INTEL-8.24.13
gl_shading_lang_version: 1.20
Compile failure in vertex shader:
ERROR: 0:1: '' :  version '330' is not supported
ERROR: 0:3: 'layout' : syntax error syntax error

Compile failure in fragment shader:
ERROR: 0:1: '' :  version '330' is not supported

Linker failure: ERROR: One or more attached shaders not successfully compiled
```

Comment: I do not think you are not showing sufficient code to diagnose the problem. Clearly some things are left out, because about half your lines are not even terminated with `;`. That said, `SDL_RENDERER_TARGETTEXTURE` is the only unusual thing about your *shown* code; that could be the cause of the fallback, your initial context may lack the necessary capabilities. Actually, scratch that, calling `glewInit (...)` on OS X is pretty unusual. This is going to generate `GL_INVALID_ENUM` in a 3.3 context on OS X unless you set `glewExperimental = GL_TRUE` first. You do not need GLEW on OS X, BTW.

Comment: What is the proper way to use OpenGL 3.x on MacOS? (For my setup the glew initialisation works and GLEW_VERSION_3_3 is true too)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are getting could be a bug, specially if the Renderer ends up working fine despite reporting "Invalid renderer".

The problem you have with SDL lowering the context version is due to the fact that the renderer is implemented with OpenGL 2.1 calls, so it needs to create a 2.1 GL context.

You could try creating the renderer first, and then set SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, etc to create a 3.3 context.

Comment: What you say about the downgrade makes sense. Of course the renderer can not work with a core profile without backward compatibility. The SDL2 source is pretty readable. I will try to figure out when the error is being set. Maybe this is caused by my unusual code setup.